# How to capture query string parameters from network tab programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-traffic, web-traffic, web-console

I am trying to capture query string parameters for analytics purpose using javascript. I did some searching and found that [BMP](https://bmp.lightbody.net/) can be used to do it but i am unable to find ample examples to implement. Could anyone point me in the right direction.

**EDIT 1:**
I used below code using `browsermob-proxy` to get har file but i get `ERROR: browsermob-proxy returned error` when i run it . I use selenium with it.

```
getHarFile() {
        const proxy = browsermb.Proxy;
        const pr = new proxy({host:"0.0.0.0",port:4444});
        pr.doHAR("http://www.cnn.com/", (err,data) => {
            if (err) {
                logger.debug('ERROR: ' + err);
            } else {
                fs.writeFileSync('ua.com.har', data, 'utf8');
                logger.debug("#HAR CREATED#");
            }
        })
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: have you read the github page, which includes reams of usage information?

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried using https://github.com/zzo/browsermob-node as an example with selenium but I  am not able to understand the use of seleniumproxy in it

Comment: @human are you trying to get the page query string or some call made through the page?

Comment: Also, are you doing BDD tests with selenium?

Comment: Parameters are encoded into the url after the `?`. So if you are able to capture the requests, then you can just url decode everything after the `?` and you will find the parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to do it using the `s` object available on chrome console. The url with encoded query string was available as `s.rb` object in chrome console. I just decoded it and extracted the query string parameters.

Comment: What is the `s` object? I tried to `console.log(s)` in the chrome console and it came back as `s is not defined`.

Comment: please specify how to get `s` object since I am not able to use that in chrome console.

Answer (score 5):

So since I´m not quite sure of your scope I will throw you some ideas:

### 1. Fixing browsermob-proxy

You should change the host and proxy of the browsermob-proxy. Change the host to 127.0.0.1 and the port with any random number (4444 its ok). Then, make sure your browser run in that host and proxy by changing the browser settings.

### 2. Using plain javascript

**2.1 Get current page query string**

You can get the query string using `location.search`. If you are using some BDD framework with selenium, it is possible to execute javascript code and retrieve the result. You should always add a `return` to your code in order to recieve the response in your BDD test.

**2.2 Using Performance API**

You can access to all the network information within [performance api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance). If you need to get the current page url you can use the following code:

```
performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")
```

This will return all the current navigation events and information.

If you want to get some information of the calls that the page made you can access it using:

```
performance.getEntriesByType("resource")
```

This will return all the calls made by your site. You have to loop over it searching the resource you want to find.

---

In all the ways, there is no way to get the value and key of query string as in the network tab. You have to separate it manually with a function, you can use the code [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/4637140) to get the value of a key.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to create your personal extension for Google Chrome, and developing an extension you can access few more apis that are not available by default in the console. 
For example you will have this object in order to inspect the network tab:

`chrome.devtools.network`

Here two links you may find useful:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network

I hope it helps

Comment: How can i use `chrome.devtools.network` inside my javascript code?

Comment: You can't as I know (maybe I am wrong). My suggestion is to create your extension in order to do what you need to do, and then you can communicate from your js to the extension if you setup a way of communication (if you need further actions). Otherwise if your end goal is just the one you describe here, simply transform your js code to the js code of a chrome extension